# Injecting Dependency That Has Already Been Created With Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject

I would like to know how to use Ninject to inject an object as a dependency where that object has already been created. I have the following code in my WPF Window_Loaded method in my main window:

```
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<ITeleStore>().To<TeleStore>();
        kernel.Bind<ITreeViewModel>().To<TreeViewModel>();

        var tst = kernel.Get<TeleStore>();

        // rootnode already exists and is obtained from the telestore component
        TstTreeNode rootNode = tst.GetRootNode();

        // how do I use ninject to inject rootnode?
        ITreeViewModel treeViewModel = new TreeViewModel(rootNode);

        base.DataContext = treeViewModel;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the root node as argument to the request! Simple to the following

```
public interfacte ITreeViewModel
{
    public TstTreeNode TestNode {get;}

    ........
    // Other members
}

// Sample Class
public class TreeViewModel : ITreeViewModel
{
    public TreeViewModel(TstTreeNode node) {
       TestNode = node;
    }

    // Implemented from interface
    public TstTreeNode TestNode {get; private set;}
}

// Your code
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<ITeleStore>().To<TeleStore>();
kernel.Bind<ITreeViewModel>().To<TreeViewModel>();

var tst = kernel.Get<TeleStore>();

// rootnode already exists and is obtained from the telestore component
TstTreeNode rootNode = tst.GetRootNode();

// how do I use ninject to inject rootnode?
ITreeViewModel treeViewModel = kernel.Get<TreeViewModel>(new ConstructorArgument("node", rootNode));
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using property-injection to set the "TstTreeNode" value in TreeViewModel class. Following is a sample code :-

```
    public interfacte ITreeViewModel
    {
        public TstTreeNode TestNode {get;set;}

        ........
        // Other members
    }

    // Sample Class
    public class TreeViewModel : ITreeViewModel
    {
        public TreeViewModel() {}

        // Implemented from interface
        public TstTreeNode TestNode {get;set;}
    }

    // Your code
    IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Bind<ITeleStore>().To<TeleStore>();
    kernel.Bind<ITreeViewModel>().To<TreeViewModel>();

    var tst = kernel.Get<TeleStore>();

    // rootnode already exists and is obtained from the telestore component
    TstTreeNode rootNode = tst.GetRootNode();

    // how do I use ninject to inject rootnode?
    ITreeViewModel treeViewModel = kernel.Get<TreeViewModel>();

    // Property Injection
    treeViewModel.TestNode = rootNode

    base.DataContext = treeViewModel;
```